# How to know unallocated disk block and make partition?

Tags: partition

`fdisk -l` shows-

```
Disk /dev/sda: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x3175fab9

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048   136718335    68358144   83  Linux
/dev/sda3       136718336   273436671    68359168   83  Linux
/dev/sda4       273438718   582242303   154401793    5  Extended
Partition 4 does not start on physical sector boundary.
/dev/sda5       273438720   289062911     7812096   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda6       289064960   582242303   146588672   83  Linux
```

I saw [Live resizing of an ext4 filesytem on linux](https://codesilence.wordpress.com/2013/03/14/live-resizing-of-an-ext4-filesytem-on-linux/) where they have shown the method of partitioning using `fdisk`. Now, I want to make a partition from unallocated disk block. But, I don't know the unallocated disk block stating and ending. How can I know this, so that, I create a partition?

Comment: `parted /dev/sda unit s print free` would show free areas if usable. `fdisk` might make suggestions when trying to create a new partition.

Comment: You have about 1M between sda3 and the extended partition (just compare start and end blocks). And the extended partition is not aligned to physical blocksize. Adjust the start of the extended parition to 2734387**20**, and the end of sda3 to 2734387**19**, and resize sda3 if you really want to invest all the effort for the additional 1M. Backup data on sda3 first (you do make regular backups, don't you?)

Comment: Also, you have space to extend the end of sda6 (and the extended partition) quite a bit.